# (Did / have done / had done) ~ ago

Tags: difference, present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple

I'm a beginner in English and I'm curious about which one sounds more natural.

1. Emailed you

> I emailed you about that a month ago.
>
> I have emailed you about that a month ago.
>
> I had emailed you about that a month ago.

2. Already told you

> I already told you about that a month ago.
>
> I have already told you about that a month ago.
>
> I had already told about that a month ago.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a past-time expression use the simple past tense, unless you need to use past perfect tense.

Present perfect "have done" is never paired with past time expressions.  Past perfect is used for events occurring before the time of the narrative (but your examples are too short to establish a time of the narrative)